# Uncaught type error while using IIFE function

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript.Trying to assign background images to div tag through this function:

```
(function(){
 
    var images=['image01.jpg','image04.jpg','image12.jpg','image22.jpg','image32.jpg','image42.jpg'];
    
    for(var index=0;index<=images.length;index++)
    {
    var images_class=document.querySelectorAll('.Image_c');
    
    let image_show=images[index];
    images_class[index].style.backgroundImage=`url(images/${image_show})`;
   
}})();
```

Background image  Style had been correctly mapped to each div of 6 div tags.
However , there is uncaught error  as below:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at index2.js:10
    at index2.js:12
(anonymous) @ index2.js:10
(anonymous) @ index2.js:12
```

Anyone can help me understand what this error mean and how to resolve it?

Comment: It means your `images` array has more elements than there are items in `images_class` node list. Just print `images_class.length` and `images.length`. They are not the same.

Comment: I tried, shows same

Comment: 6
index2.js:6 6
index2.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at index2.js:12
    at index2.js:14
(anonymous) @ index2.js:12
(anonymous) @ index2.js:14

Comment: (function(){
 
    var images=['image01.jpg','image04.jpg','image12.jpg','image22.jpg','image32.jpg','image42.jpg'];
    console.log(images.length);
    var x = document.querySelectorAll('.Image_c');
    console.log(x.length);
    for(var index=0;index<=x.length;index++)
    {
    
   
    let image_show=images[index];
    x[index].style.backgroundImage=`url(images/${image_show})`;
   
}})();  But the error still showing up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to loop the queryselector object as the length of images array would me more than length of object returned from query selector

```
var images=['image01.jpg','image04.jpg','image12.jpg','image22.jpg','image32.jpg','image42.jpg'];
var x = document.querySelectorAll
for(var index=0;index<x.length;index++)
{

let image_show=images[index];
x[index].style.backgroundImage=`url(images/${image_show})`;
```

Comment: (function(){
 
    var images=['image01.jpg','image04.jpg','image12.jpg','image22.jpg','image32.jpg','image42.jpg'];
    console.log(images.length);
    var x = document.querySelectorAll('.Image_c');
    console.log(x.length);
    for(var index=0;index<=x.length;index++)
    {
    
   
    let image_show=images[index];
    x[index].style.backgroundImage=`url(images/${image_show})`;
   
}})();

Comment: Error msg: index2.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at index2.js:12
    at index2.js:14
(anonymous) @ index2.js:12
(anonymous) @ index2.js:14